# Raytracing / Phong Model Diffuse component

Tags: c++, graphics, phong

So I'm having trouble with the Phong Model specifically the diffuse component and using the right normal vector and direction to light vector. This is for a school project but I don't care if I don't finish it as long as someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong. I've already tried a few things and the best I do was get half of the larger sphere to shade but in the wrong direction. The brightest intensity is on the outer edge of the circle half and gets darker as it goes to the center when it should be the other way around. It looks like its shading the sphere in lines when I've seen models that look like it's shading in empty circles.

The shading of the second sphere may be hard to see.
[image: Shaded spheres]

Relevant Structures:

```
struct Ray
{
    vec3 origin;        // origin of the ray
    vec3 dir;           // direction of the ray
};

struct Sphere
{   
    vec3 center;
    float radius;       
    vec3 ka, kd, ks;
    vec3 reflectivity;
    float alpha;        

    Sphere(const vec3& ic=vec3(0.0f), const float& ir=0.0f, const vec3& ika=vec3(0.0f), const vec3& ikd=vec3(0.0f), const vec3& iks=vec3(0.0f), const float& ireflectivity=0.1f, const float& ialpha=1.0f):
    center(ic), radius(ir), ka(ika), kd(ikd), ks(iks), reflectivity(ireflectivity), alpha(ialpha)
    {}

    bool intersect(const Ray& ray, float& t0, float& t1);
};

struct PointLight
{
    vec3 location;
    vec3 id, is;    

    PointLight(const vec3& iloc=vec3(0.0f), const vec3& iid=vec3(0.0f), const vec3& iis=vec3(0.0f)):
    location(iloc), id(iid), is(iis)
    {}

};

    vec3 color;
    vec3 amb = my_sphere.ka* my_ambient_light.ia;   // I = ka * ia  ambient component
    int temp = my_point_lights.size() - 1;
    color += amb;

    vec3 diff;
    for (int i = my_point_lights.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        vec3 n = (ray.origin + ray.dir - my_sphere.center);
        normalize(n);

        vec3 L = (my_point_lights[temp].location - ray.origin);
        normalize(L);

        diff += my_sphere.kd * my_point_lights[temp].id * std::max(dot(n, L), 0.0f);
    }
    color += diff;
```

Comment: I think that you shouldn't subtract ray.origin from vec3 L. Try to follow this link: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XlXGDj

Comment: I believe to get the direction to light vector I need to subtract the surface position from the point light position. Which may also be the point of intersection between the ray and sphere so ray.origin could work. The link you shared is similar to some examples I've seen but the light direction and sphere position are given in that example. The normal does look similar to mine. that's probably where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

What you basically seem to want to do in your shader is compute the diffuse shading of a given point on a sphere. For that you'll basically need two things: First, the surface normal at that point on the sphere you want to shade, and, second, the direction from which the light is falling onto the point you want to shade. Now, before you can go ahead and compute the shading of an object at a given point, you'll generally need to know the actual position of that particular point you want to shade. Since you didn't really provide any explanation what exactly things like `ray.dir` actually represent in your code, I'll have to resort to guesswork. I assume that what you're doing is some sort of raytracing in a fragment shader. And I'll have to assume that `ray.dir` is not just some vector pointing in the general direction of the ray that hit the sphere at the point you're interested in, but it actually is *the* vector that will bring you from the start of the ray to the exact hit point on the sphere. Otherwise, you're lacking the most essential information to really do anything, which is the coordinates of the point you wanna shade. In that case, you'll first have to compute where the actual intersection of your ray and your sphere lies.

Now, if we make all these assumptions, and we furthermore assume that all these vectors you have actually represent coordinates in the same coordinate system, then `ray.origin + ray.dir - my_sphere.center` should indeed yield a vector pointing from the center of the sphere to the point you want to shade. And that vector should indeed point in the direction of the surface normal of the sphere at the point you want to shade. However, the second vector you need to compute the diffuse shading is a vector pointing into the direction from which the light is falling onto the point you want to shade. That is, a vector pointing from the point to shade to the light source. However, `my_point_lights[temp].location - ray.origin` would seem to be a vector pointing from the ray origin to the light source instead.

Apart from that, it should probably be brought to your attention that, contrary to what you seem to be under the impression of, the function `normalize(x)` does not modify the vector you pass as an argument. It simply returns another vector that is the normalized version of whatever vector you feed to it. So, most likely, what you actually meant to write is

```
n = normalize(n);
…
L = normalize(L);
```

Also, you accumulate values in `color` and `diff`, yet you never initialize these vectors to anything. You probably meant to initialize them to zero…

Comment: You were right to assume that ray.dir is a vector. It is the direction vector of the ray. I just updated it to include that. This is basically most of the information I have to work with. So my thought process was that I need the direction to light vector which is in all directions for wherever the light reflects off the sphere's surface. Since ray.origin is the point of intersection of a point of surface of the sphere and the ray. I thought I need to subtract a point on the surface of the sphere from the point light location to get the direction to light vector.

Comment: @JRat Well ok, if it is just the direction of the ray and nothing more, however, then what exactly do you think that `ray.origin + ray.dir - my_sphere.center` gives you!?

Comment: I thought this was the normal of sphere surface. A friend told me it should be the ray.origin - my_sphere.center but some examples I've seen use ray.origin + ray.dir * t - my_sphere.center. Like the one Felipe shared.